# Can you see which addresses sent you money using your viewkey?

Tags: privacy, viewkey

Alternative title: Would Monero cryptography be a possible way to do secret voting?

While researching smart contracts and online voting, I came up with the following idea: Give everyone 1 Monero (or a smaller denomination) and make a Monero address for each possible votable option.

Would this be a viable option? In which I mean, can you see who voted for a specific proposal, given the viewkey of the votable options? Phrased differently: is it possible to see which address sent a transaction using the viewkey of the receiving Monero address?

I know Monero uses ring signatures to hide the actual UTXO used, in my understanding ringCT just makes multiple other UTXOs equally likely. When talking about online voting that would be broken pretty easily, knowing when the original 1 Monero was distributed to everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Monero does not allow a receiver to determine the address of who sent the received money, whether using the receiver's secret view or spend keys. This information is private to the sender only. The sender may supply an offline proof that they are the one who sent the money, however, but that's an extra, optional step for them.

Voting is usually an anonymous affair anyway, so knowing who cast a vote for a particular outcome is typically not needed.